# 代表你的猴山; why can it be used in this way?

Tags: etymology

In the show I am watching the protagonist asked a person with the surname 猴：

> 你是代表你的猴山還是代表最高反貪總局？

Obviously, he means

> Are you expressing your private opinion, or the order of the supreme anti corruption office?

But why can the opinion of someone named 猴 be called 猴山？ none of mydictionaries list this！

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

猴山 is the metaphor for his interest group, his friends are treated as monkeys, his group are treated as a mountain.

Comment: Is this related to 西遊記?

Comment: @Philipp Not necessarily. It's similar to 鸡窝, 牛棚, 狗洞, 猪圈 which refer to 'messy', 'rough', 'miserable', 'poor' place separately, that place is usually for living or work. 猴山, a funny satire.

Comment: If my surname was 陸，would people use 猴山 or 陸山， or none of the two？

Comment: People might use 猴山, if people want to add your surname to emphasize your family, they might use 陆家